# Changing Only Single List Tile in List View so it's Unique in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if it was possible to make items in List View unique in the sense that if I want to add something to the one, it only changes that particular list tile item, for example, if I added a leading icon from the DropDown to the one on the list, it adds that icon only to that particular list tile, and not the others (I can then add other icons from the dropdown to other list tile items).

Here's the code for it, I am not sure if this is possible since the builder is made from Bloc and an existing class Person, basically a template for each list item. I have tried with adding UniqueKey(), but that seems not to do anything. Here's the code for the List View:

**_chosenSize**

```
String _chosenSize;

child: BlocConsumer<PersonBloc, List<Person>>(
    builder: (context, personList) {
      return ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          print("personList: $personList");

          Person person = personList[index];
          return ListTile(
          key: UniqueKey() //added unique key here, but it still fails
          //for example, is it possible to make this list tile unique
          //if I make change to it, it only changes the one I change, and not
          //all of them in a list at once
          leading: _buildSize(); //DROPDOWN HERE
          
              trailing: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text("${person.name} ${person.age}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
              subtitle: Text(
                "person.name",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              onTap: () => showDialog(context, person, index));
        },
        itemCount: personList.length,
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            Divider(color: Colors.black),
      );
    },
    listener: (BuildContext context, personList) {},
  ),
```

Then here's the code for the DropDown:

```
Widget _buildSize() {
return DropdownButton<String>(
  focusColor: Colors.white,
  value: _chosenSize,
  //elevation: 5,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  iconEnabledColor: Colors.black,
  items: <String>[
    '',
    'S',
    'M',
    'L',
    'XL',
  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
  hint: Text(
    "Size",
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
  ),
  onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {
      _chosenSize = value;
    });
  },
)};
```

What happens is that when I change the 'size' option from the dropdown, it changes for all list tiles, I need it to change only for one and then save the state of it. Here's what happens:

[image]

Comment: Where did you define the `_chosenSize` variable?

Comment: I declared it on top of the class itself as an empty string: String _chosenSize; Added it to main post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a list for _chosenSize as well, which you pass to `Widget _buildSize(String _chosenSize)` with `_buildSize(_chosenSize[index])` and also store it there with onChanged

```dart
class MyPageState extends State<MyPage> { 
List<String> _chosenSizes = [];

...

return ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          print("personList: $personList");

          Person person = personList[index];
          return ListTile(
          key: UniqueKey() //added unique key here, but it still fails
          //for example, is it possible to make this list tile unique
          //if I make change to it, it only changes the one I change, and not
          //all of them in a list at once
          leading: _buildSize(index]); //DROPDOWN HERE
          
              trailing: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text("${person.name} ${person.age}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
              subtitle: Text(
                "person.name",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
              onTap: () => showDialog(context, person, index));
        },
        itemCount: personList.length,
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            Divider(color: Colors.black),
      );
      
      ...
      
      Widget _buildSize(int index) {
return DropdownButton<String>(
  focusColor: Colors.white,
  value: _chosenSizes[index],

...

  onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {
      _chosenSizes[index] = value;
    });
  },
)};

}
```

Comment: Oh, you are probably correct. The _chosenSize is only declared as an empty string on top of the class.

Comment: I really appreciate the response, could you please just add it to the code, since I am not sure where exactly to insert it? I added how I declared the _chosenSize in the main post.

Comment: See the edit - actually it is smarter to only pass the index to _buildSize()

Comment: If this helped you, accepting the answer would be a nice gesture

Comment: Of course, it totally did, I've been thinking about how to finish this for a while. Thank you, it's very much appreciated!